# RecursiveAction/ForkJoinPool with Blocking I/O

Tags: java, concurrency

I've got a Java client that needs to recursively call a server to retrieve a large data graph - requiring approximately one thousand calls.  I have no control of the server, and this is required for a time-critical crash recovery scenario.

My problem is that I need my original thread to block until all calls have completed.

The RecursiveAction and ForkJoinPool abstractions from java.util.concurrent are precisely what I need, except that they are designed for CPU parallelism and forbid use of blocking I/O.

So, what would be the best way to implement recursive network calls, with the initiating thread blocking until all calls have completed?

Additional context info:

- I can't modify the server.
- The server allows and supports this kind of heavy querying.
- I will restrict the number of concurrent network calls to something like 10-30.
- Caching the data on disk is not feasible.

Additional thoughts: would a single-phase Phaser be appropriate, in conjunction with a ThreadPoolExecutor?  Call tasks would call Phaser.register(), make the call, submit child tasks and then call Phaser.arrive().  The initiating thread would call Phaser.awaitAdvance(1).  Would this be the most appropriate approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got this working well using JDK1.7 Phasers.  The pattern I used was something like this:

```
private void loadGraphFromServer() {
    final Phaser phaser = new Phaser(1); // "1" registers the calling thread
    for (final Item item : getDataListFromServer()) {
        phaser.register();
        executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    getMoreDataFromServer(item.getSomeId());
                    // more nested loops/tasks/calls here...
                }
                finally {
                    phaser.arrive();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    phaser.arriveAndAwaitAdvance(); // blocks until all tasks are complete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a fixed size executor pool.  You can set the maximum size to 10 to 30 threads and lot it up with all 1000 requests, or add 1 request which create two more, and those two more etc.  You can wait for all these request to complete with shutdown() and awaitTermination()

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use shutdown/awaitTermination because the initiating thread doesn't know when the last task has been submitted.

Comment: Each task can wait on the tasks it creates. It can do tail optimisation i.e. don't create another task if its the last thing its going to do.

Comment: But then I'd run out of threads... unless I'm missing something.